# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node.js.  I created a file named `app.js` and put this code in that file using express to switch the template engine:

```
//module dependencies

var express = require('express');
    routes = require ('./routes');
    user = require ('./routes/user');
    http= require ('http');
    path = require ('path');

var exphbs = require ('express3-handlebars');
var app = express();

//all environement
app.set ('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname +'/views');
//app.set('view engine','jade');
app.engine('handlebars',exphbs({defaultLayout :'main'}));
app.set('view engine ','handlebars');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//developpement only
if ('developpement' == app.get('env')){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//app.get('/', routes.index);
//app.get ('/user' , user.list);
app.get('/' , function(req,res) {
    res.render('home');
}
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Then I run the application and get this error:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

This line is causing the error:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
```

Comment: missing `)`. plz close.

Comment: One line above the error.

Comment: `app.get('/' , function(req,res) {
    res.render('home');
}` should be `app.get('/' , function(req,res) {
    res.render('home');
});`

Comment: what about this :  module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\nodeapps\test\node_modules\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3

Comment: By the way, you are leaking variables into global scope like a broken toilet... either put `var` in front of every variable declaration or use colons instead of semicolons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace in

```
app.get('/' , function(req,res) {
  res.render('home');
}) // <-- the last one
```

You should use an editor that provides proper syntax highlighting and a code linter - like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) which would warn you about this and also warn you about improper variable declarations:

```
var onevar = 'value'; // <-- superbad! You just ended this statement!
    another = 'val2'; // <-- now this variable leaked into global scope!
// Proper:
var onevar = 'value';
var another = 'val2';
// Also proper:
var onevar = 'value',
    another = 'val2';
```

The `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is always a typo (or you trying to do something JavaScript does not understand) somewhere in your code and usually happens **before** the unexpected identifier. Oversimplified, it basically means that the parser was in the middle of some statement and, according to the grammar rules, the thing that followed was not acceptable for that particular situation.

Comment: ok i correct the code but i got this error :                    Error: Cannot find module './routes'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodeapps\test\app.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

Comment: The file must be in the same directory as the one from which you require it. It seems to be not...

Comment: Does it have .js extension? This should not be necessary, but try to include the extension in the require call.

Answer (score 3):

I think this incorrect:

```
var express = require('express');
    routes = require ('./routes');
    user = require ('./routes/user');
    http= require ('http');
    path = require ('path');
```

I think you must try something like that:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require ('./routes'),
    user = require ('./routes/user'),
    http= require ('http'),
    path = require ('path');
```

Or

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require ('./routes');
var user = require ('./routes/user');
var http= require ('http');
var path = require ('path');
```

Comment: what about this error dave : Error: Cannot find module './routes' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15 at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Module.require (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodeapps\test\app.js:4:14) at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

Comment: @NafaLamine what is in the .   ('./routes') for your machine?  The path doesn't exist. It would seem.